# Debug tab is not available on the project properties page of a C# web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I'm trying to access the DEBUG tab on the project properties page of a C# web app but there is no such tab (Visual Studio 2010)

The project is a web application project.

Anyone knows how to make the debug tab visible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "Debug" tag in project properties for web application projects. This tab is only available in C# Windows and Console projects.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may want to look at the 'Build' or the 'Web' tab for options that you may expect to find under the 'Debug' tag. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see. I wanted to remote debug my web app. So it's not possible then? I can't find any kind of reference to remote debugging in these tabs unfortunately.

Comment: I can see now. Remote debugging is not supported over the internet. 

"The remote device and the Visual Studio computer must be connected over a network or connected directly through an Ethernet cable. Debugging over the internet is not supported."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx

Thanks.