# Can't set MVC startup view for debug in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 RC with an ASP.NET MVC app and can't set the view to load for debugging. All the documentation I've found points to editing the project settings and changing the Web tab. There is no web tab on the properties of this app; only Application, Build, Debug.

I'd like to set the startup page to web.app > wwwroot/Views/Home/index.cshtml

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1** Here's the code from the Startup.cs file for routing; using a breakpoint, I verified that we hit the code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
{
    // other code here...

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2** I upgraded my Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 to RC recently and this issue started about that time. I didn't uninstall the CTP but installed RC on top of it. Could that cause this issue?

Here's what the property window looks like on VS 2015 RC; there's no Web tab (described on the MSDN blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/23/aspnet-5-updates-for-feb-2015.aspx)):

[image]

**UPDATE 3** Here's the image next to the project name:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: If you cant do either of these options then what you have there is not a MVC project

If this project is an authentic MVC app it should have the Web tab because its a web project. Then the following steps would apply.

```
Right click your Web project
Select Properties
Go to Web tab
Tick Specific Page 
Enter Home/Index (You have to treat it as what you would see in the URL)
```

In case this is some how a web project and it does not have the web tab then you can try using the route config.  If there is no route config then this is not a mvc project.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            //This line below will set the default action to go to
            defaults: new {controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces : new[] {"ProjectName.Controllers"}
);
```

Comment: Thanks, @imGreg. The routing is correct in the Startup.cs file (please see update above). And I put a breakpoint there to ensure the code was hitting it. But the app opens the web.app > wwwroot > Index.html file instead of the view. Is it possible that the project type is wrong and it's not a web app? How can I check that? When I hit F5, it opens the app in the browser, so that part is working right.

Comment: What is the symbol next to the project name in your solution explorer?

Comment: imGreg: Please see Update 3 to question above.

Comment: @Alex Can you verify how you made this project step by step so we can rule out if this is a MVC or not.   Also, I do not think going from CTP to RC will affect MVC to the point where there is no Web tab in the properties.  All web projects MVC or WebForm or WebApi should have a Web tab.

Comment: @Alex after searching around for why you dont have a web tab I came across this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734470/debug-tab-is-not-available-on-the-project-properties-page-of-a-c-sharp-web-app). This is saying Debug tab doesn't exist in a Web App which I notice in my projects also

Comment: Thanks, @imGreg. What's strange is why the startup page would suddenly change. Like something broke the settings. Let me know if there's any other info you need that might help track this down. Another approach: Is it possible to change the project type?

Comment: Also, just now, after a reboot, I've lost IISExpress from my debug options. It just says "Start". Argggh!

Comment: I would make a new project using the same step you did with this project and see if you get the same result aka no web tab and such.  You might need to just set the project at Set as Startup project again thats all.  Referring to your reboot comment